# How to perform mathematical operations on all CSV file columns & rows using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my code:

```
all_data = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
mu = np.array([all_data.mean(0)])
sigma = np.array([np.std(all_data,axis=0)])
print(all_data.shape)
print(mu.shape)
print(sigma.shape)
```

> Output:
>
> (20, 24)
>
> (1, 24)
>
> (1, 24)

Sigma and Mu are numpy array or matrix.

I want to perform this operaiton:

> all_data = (all_data - mu)/sigma

Here, first column (all rows), of `all_data` first gets substracted by first column of `mu` and then divided by first column of `sigma`

second column (all rows) of `all_data` first gets substracted by second column of `mu` and then divided by second column of `sigma`

Like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with the underlying numpy arrays of your dataframe, the broadcasting takes care of the work for you:

```
(all_data.values - mu)/sigma
```

And put it back in a dataframe with the same columns/index as `all_data`:

```
pd.DataFrame((all_data.values - mu)/sigma, columns=all_data.columns, index=all_data.index)
```

**Example**:

On this mini dataframe:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(5,5)))
>>> all_data
   0  1  2  3  4
0  5  7  1  8  6
1  5  8  0  3  0
2  8  2  0  1  6
3  5  8  7  7  0
4  4  6  0  2  5
```

With:

```
mu = np.array([all_data.mean(0)])
sigma = np.array([np.std(all_data,axis=0)])

>>> mu
array([[5.6, 2. , 4. , 4.4, 7.6]])
>>> sigma
array([[1.62480768, 1.26491106, 3.40587727, 2.41660919, 0.48989795]])
```

You can get:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame((all_data.values - mu)/sigma, columns=all_data.columns, index=all_data.index)
          0         1        2         3          4
0 -0.369274  3.952847 -0.88083  1.489691  -3.265986
1 -0.369274  4.743416 -1.17444 -0.579324 -15.513435
2  1.477098  0.000000 -1.17444 -1.406930  -3.265986
3 -0.369274  4.743416  0.88083  1.075888 -15.513435
4 -0.984732  3.162278 -1.17444 -0.993127  -5.307228
```

Feel free the check the math, but it satisfies your requirements: the operation is applied on the first column of the dataframe with the first values of `sigma` and `mu`, second column with second values, etc...

Answer (score 0):

how about `numpy.matlib.repmat`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(20, 24))
mu = np.array([all_data.mean(0)])
sigma = np.array([np.std(all_data,axis=0)])

MU = pd.DataFrame(numpy.matlib.repmat(mu,20, 1))
SIGMA = pd.DataFrame(numpy.matlib.repmat(sigma,20, 1))
all_data = (all_data - MU)/SIGMA
```